# How to fix unsimplifed Sqrts?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

The following code produces two values for the variable p.  But the results contain `Sqrt[k^2]`.  This should just be reduced to k, because the sign ambiguity is already covered by there being separate solutions for the +/- cases.  Is there some good reason *Mathematica* is going this that I'm missing?  How can I make it do the simplificaiton?

```
t = FullSimplify[Solve[(1 - p)^2 + (k^2)*(c + 5/4) == 0, p]]

(*   {{p -> 1 - 1/2 Sqrt[-(5 + 4 c) k^2]}, 

      {p -> 1 + 1/2 Sqrt[-(5 + 4 c) k^2]}}     *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
FullSimplify[Solve[(1 - p)^2 + (k^2)*(c + 5/4) == 0, p], 
Assumptions -> {k \[Element] Reals && k > 0}]
```

Comment: No, k can be complex.  What I said about the sign ambiguity of Sqrt[k^2] already being accounted for still holds when k is complex.

Answer (score 2):

It does this because in general, `Sqrt[k^2]` is not necessarily equal to `k`.  But you can force the simplification you are looking for like this,

```
FullSimplify[
  Solve[(1 - p)^2 + (k^2)*(c + 5/4) == 0, 
   p]] /. {Sqrt[Times[a_, Power[b_, 2]]] :> b Sqrt[a]}
(* {{p -> 1 - 1/2 Sqrt[-5 - 4 c] k}, 
    {p -> 1 + 1/2 Sqrt[-5 - 4 c] k}} *)
```

Comment: Do you get my point, though, that MMa should do this, because the two solutions cover the sign ambiguity?

Comment: I don't see it that way, `FullSimplify` is going to work on each solution independently.  I do see the point that in this case you aren't losing any generality by making this simplification, but it just seems like one of those special cases where human intervention is needed.

Answer (score 2):

Why not to make this:

```
 t = Simplify[Solve[(1 - p)^2 + (k^2)*(c + 5/4) == 0, p], k > 0]
(*  {{p -> 1 - 1/2 Sqrt[-5 - 4 c] k}, {p -> 1 + 1/2 Sqrt[-5 - 4 c] k}}  *)
```

and then to treat  `k` as a complex number?

Answer (score 2):

If you are certain that pulling the `k` out of the square-root is harmless, then I suggest you use `PowerExpand`:

```
Solve[(1 - p)^2 + (k^2)*(c + 5/4) == 0, p] // Simplify // PowerExpand
```

> $\{\{p \rightarrow 1 - \frac{1}{2} i \sqrt{5 + 4 c} k\}, \{p \rightarrow 1 + \frac{1}{2} i \sqrt{5 + 4 c} k\}\}$